# Shopify Products Import CSV Validation error invalid file

Tags: csv, shopify

When importing a CSV for adding new products I get an invalid file error for the image source. Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

Here's an example of the error message: Line 2: Validation failed: /images/311190.jpg is not a valid image file type.

Comment: Make sure the image URLs are valid and accessible.

Comment: The files are named using sku which is all numeric .jpg for example 317580.jpg

Comment: I’m able to access them using mobile device

Comment: Here is an example of the error message: Line 2: Validation failed: /images/311190.jpg is not a valid image file type.

Comment: You need provider full URLs, not only paths.

Comment: It only uses paths in the error message but in the csv I’m providing full urls

Comment: Can you provide the full URL?